# Is merging 43 commits from master into feature branch "harder" than merging 1 commit the other way?

Tags: git

Scenario: I have a feature branch (let's call it `feature`) which have been laying stale for the last month. Meanwhile I've done 43 commits to the `master` branch. The `feature` branch has only one commit deviating from the master branch at that point. Now I want to continue to work on the feature, but with the latest master branch changes applied. I have a few options:

1. Merge the `master` branch onto the `feature` branch (43 commits)
2. Open a new branch `feature-continued` at the `master` tip and merge `feature` in here (1 commit)
3. Rebase `feature` to the `master` tip (43 commits)

Is there any reasons to choose one over the other? My concerns are

1. Which gives the best workflow
2. Which gives least chance of merge conflict (if any difference)
3. Which has smallest impact on the repo size and complexity (if any difference)

Method 1 and 3 gives the impression of that these are "tougher" operations. That these constitute a bigger change. A lot more commits to push, etc. Is it really? Aren't we basically doing the same in all cases - merging two branches?

Comment: Personally I'd go with 3, as it would likely result in a cleaner history. I don't really think any of these operations are "harder" than the others. Like you said, they're all pretty much equivalent from the perspective of resolving conflicts.

Comment: But you can't rebase if I've pushed both branches (or only one?) to a central repo, right? I just realized I have.

Comment: @Nilzor you can't rebase a branch you have pushed. But you could delete your `feature` branch in the central repo and push it again after the rebase. You also should make sure that no other team member has a local copy.

Comment: @Nilzor Well you can, but it is a bit more complicated since you have to delete history on the central repo. The important thing is that you  don't "rewrite history" (which is what git rebase does) for branches that other people are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of a question of phylosophy but to me the only way is to rebase `feature` onto `master`. Let's take a look at the other two options:

1. If you merge `master` to `feature` you create a merge commit that contains all the 43 commits from before. If you then merge `feature` back into `master` this will create a history in your master branch which is confusing at best.
2. You could create a new branch but I'd consider this a unclean workflow. Also merging the one commit could possibly lead to the same conflicts than a rebase.

Now lets analyze option 3 for your concerns:

1. I think it's pretty obvious that you'll have a clean workflow
2. A [merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) considers all commits since the branch as one change and uses this as comparison. A rebase tries to repeat the changes of a single commit on a new basis. In your case you would compare the same states with each other (because you want to merge `master` to `feature` and not the other way around). Anyway with the rebase you would try to "merge" the smaller change into the bigger one. This should make possible conflicts easier to resolve.
3. No complexity added because you'll still have one branch with one commit afterwards

Comment: Do you have any evidence or reasoning to support your remarks about option 1 being more susceptible to conflicts? Aren't you merging the same changes either way? Same for your remarks on rebase causing less conflicts (especially in this case where there's only one commit).

Comment: @Ajedi32 Just noticed that myself ;-) Does my edit make any sense?

Comment: I'm not sure. I get how intuitively you might think merging a larger changeset into a smaller one would result in more conflicts than the other way around, but is it really any different from git's perspective?

Comment: @Ajedi32 from the plain git perspective: no! But in my experience the merge tools seem to behave more nicely if the right hand change is the smaller one :-)

Comment: Any comment on concern 3 - repo _size_? Does one matter over the other?

Comment: @Nilzor Not significantly. In case 1 and 2 you add an extra commit that should be about the same size. With a rebase there is no extra commit but one commit isn't that big in relation, even with many changes.